# Access to object after ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have this ajax jquery code:

```
$("#serial_number").submit(function(e) {

    var url = "/getVoucher"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: url,
       data: $("#serial_number").serialize(),
               dataType: "json",
       success: function(data)
       {
        console.log(data);

       }
     });

     e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

and I get this fron console.log:
[image]

How I can access to object Code element?

I try with: data.Code also try data.Description but browser give me error... How to access inside success function in ajax code?

Comment: looks like it's double nested if you are still seeing `data` in the console log, try `data.data.Code`?

Comment: yes, that was an error ... Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `console.log` a variable, the output in the console are it's contents, so if you are still seeing:

```
Object{ data: Object }
```

That means that the variable `data` has a key `data` inside of it. Try:

```
console.log( data.data.Code );
```

To access the object's contents.